# Segfault while finding the index of a char* in a char**

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, arrays

I have this function that takes a char** and a char* as parameters and it's supposed to return either the index of the char* in char** or return -1 if it's not in the string array. The error I'm sure is the `while(arr[i] != NULL)...` but I'm not sure how else to do it.

```
int isInArray(char** arr, char* str) {
        int i = 0;
        while(arr[i] != NULL) {
                if(strcmp(arr[i], str) == 0)
                        return i;
                i++;
        }
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: looks fine. Please post what you send as arguments. Your code assumes the array ends with a NULL pointer which I'm guessing it dont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to set the last `char*` element of `arr` to NULL. If you can't do that, then you should introduce a third argument `size_t arr_len` to pass the length of `arr`.

Unrelated tip: since you're not modifying `*str` or `*arr`, be const-correct and use:

```
int isInArray(const char* const* arr, const char* str)
```

Comment: thanks for the tip and yeah you're right, I forgot I originally was putting NULL at the end but I didn't like that and got rid of it and just forgot about that function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your error is that you do not have the length of you array.
arr[i] can cause your programming to read bad memory.

add a "int length" parameter to your function, then use
for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
instead of the while. 
That way you will never go outside the bounds of the array, which is not guaranteed by the (arr[i] != NULL)